# Predict True/false with non numeric data

Tags: machine-learning

I have a data set with the following columns

[image]

I need to predict the last column named "**Call_Attended**" which is either **True/False**.

Could someone please help me in identifying what method should be used to predict it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest? **Logistic Regression** or [Logit](https://www.ibm.com/topics/logistic-regression)

1. Logit is appropriate when your feature variables are numeric, logical, and even oridinal.
2. And, You have a binary response variable, T/F (0,1)
3. Logistic regression can produce a simple 'explanatory' probabilities of success or failure. The probability cut-off can be adjusted to be more or less inclusive, depending on your need.
4. Logit also gives Odds for a situation or, more accurately, log-odds. The odds can give a nice indication of the models worth or utility. For example, If the odds are 1:1 or 5:1 in favor of 'True', that to me is easy to see.
5. Logit can be used for feature selection. It is also a great first step because it will help you determine the independent variable's importance. This could easily help one if you have to choose another variable to add or not.
6. Given the nature of your question, Logit Regression is 'one of the first' models that any data analyst learns.
7. For text variables, sometimes a simple replacement of x -> c(0,1,2) is all you need.

;))

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article this might be helpful to you. https://www.learndatasci.com/glossary/binary-classification/

Comment: Thanks for this, but im looking for something which can take text based data as input. Or am I missing something?

Comment: There are various algorithms which takes text based data as a input. Find out it https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-model-comparison-and-selection-5eb066197568

Comment: It does not look like you need text based features. These features look categorical and numeric.